# Expected number of siblings in a family

Tags: probability, statistics

The question goes as follows: Given a family where the number of children is a random variable $(\mu=1.8, \sigma=0.36)$, if one selects a child randomly, what’s the expected number of siblings the child has?

I stumbled upon this problem while reading Sheldon Ross’s a first course to probability as I’m an undergrad in Physics, still early in my studies, just entered my 2nd year and I’m trying to get a grasp on probability.

Any guide towards the solution will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks for the help in advance,
Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected number of siblings, given the expectation of children in a family](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460415/expected-number-of-siblings-given-the-expectation-of-children-in-a-family)